# Understanding equations of motion for mass around Schwarzschild black hole

Tags: general-relativity, computational-physics

I want to create a program that simulates general relativity 2 body problem.

I am trying to understand the following equations of motion for mass around Schwarzschild black hole which are taken from [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-body_problem_in_general_relativity#Orbits_about_the_central_mass):

> $$\displaystyle \left( \frac{dr}{d\varphi} \right)^2 = \frac{r^4}{b^2} - \left( 1 - \frac{r_s}{r} \right) \left( \frac{r^4}{a^2} + r^2 \right)$$
>
> $$\displaystyle \varphi = \int \frac{1}{r^2} \left[\frac{1}{b^2} - \left(1 - \frac{r_\mathrm{s}}{r}\right) \left(\frac{1}{a^2} + \frac{1}{r^2} \right)\right]^{-1/2} \, dr$$

I don't understand why the equation of motion is $\phi$ function of $r$. How it is derived from the above differential equation? Also, shouldn't it be the other way around: $r$ function of $\phi$: $r(\phi)$? What are some advantages of the equation of motion in $\phi (r)$ form?

I wonder if it is possible to calculate the trajectory of mass around the black hole by applying Euler's method to the following differential equation

$$\displaystyle \frac{dr}{d\varphi} = \sqrt{\frac{r^4}{b^2} - \left( 1 - \frac{r_s}{r} \right) \left( \frac{r^4}{a^2} + r^2 \right)}$$

for $r(\phi)$? Will that work?

Comment: For a simulation, don’t you need to know the *time-dependence* of $r$ and $\varphi$?

Comment: *What are some advantages of the equation of motion in $\varphi(r)$ form?* That you can obtain a formula for it. It comes out that way because of how separation of variables works on that differential equation.

Comment: Euler’s method is conceptually important but for actual work it’s more or less useless. You would need to use a more accurate numerical method.

Comment: Trying to solve _any_ ODE involving a square root term will require _much more_ sophistication than even, say, RK4!  Incidentally this is not a 2-body problem; it is a single body moving in a static potential.

Comment: *How it is derived from the above differential equation?* Rearrange the differential equation to have the form $dt=f(r)dr$, then integrate both sides. This is called “separation of variables” because all the $t$-stuff is on one side and all the $r$-stuff on the other. Not all ODEs can be solved in this way.

Comment: [Exact solution for $r(\phi)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_geodesics#Exact_solution_using_elliptic_functions)

Comment: My comment about square roots above _only_ applies if the value of the argument can be zero or negative, or course!